# knitR - How do I keep a tex file?

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I have started using knitR and latex and am liking the quality of the output (previously used R markdown). In an `.Rnw` file is it possible to specify to keep the intermediate tex file that is created on conversion as there are some things I would like to change in the tex file for formatting purposes and it would be easier to do that as I go, rather than all at the end. Currently whenever I 'Compile pdf' in `knitr`, the tex file is replaced. I have read you can do this in an `.Rmd` file, but I can't see how to specify in `.Rnw`.

Thanks

Comment: This questions seems to be the result of a misconseption. When the RNW is compiled to PDF, the conversion order is RNW --> TEX --> PDF. Therefore, the TEX file will be overwritten each time. The "keep TEX" option means that the TEX file is not deleted after the PDF has been created. It does *not* mean that the TEX file is not overwritten.

Comment: As @CL mention the file will be overwritten each time by Rstudio (which uses `knitr`) when you click "Compile pdf". What type of formatting do you do that you cannot do in the `.Rnw` file?

Answer (score 0):

just knit to .tex:

`library("knitr"); knit("input.Rnw", output="input.tex")`